# How to print into browser console using golang

Tags: go, console, webbrowser-control

i am using golang to develop my small web app and i just wanted to know are there are any ways in golang from which i can print anything into browser console.

I am using Go version go1.7.4 linux/amd64.

Here i just want to print some values for example redirect url's into web browser's console
[image]

Answer (score 3):

No.

Go doesn't run in your browser (unless you're using [GopherJS](https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs) or similar), so there's no way for *Go* to write to your browser's console.  You must do that from JavaScript.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh..thank you